# Firewall rules specific to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-firewall

I have a VPN connection to my remote Win08 server running Windows Firewall w/ Adv. Sec. I open all ports to a handful of specific IPs which gives me ability to connect with Remote Desktop Connection as well as access to the file system (mapping network drives).

Now i'm trying to configure access to the sql server. Working from my local MSSMS I can see the remote Database Engine in the 'Browse for Servers | Network Servers' dialog. But I can't actually establish a connection (the standard *'cannot connect to...'* error dialog pasted below) until i turn off the 'Private Profile' of the firewall.

So the firewall rule that grants access to File Sharing and Remote Desktop Connection is not granting access to the SQL Server. Where do I look for additional config options?

> ### TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to myBoxName.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: 1326)

Comment: Did you create a rule to allow incoming connections on Sql port 1433?

Comment: io using the named pipes provider, you could try to configure the client to only use TCP connections.

Comment: The existing rule is set to allow any port, program, protocol ...checking that TCP connection angle now.

Comment: Checked that TCP connection angle - no joy. The error message changed to reflect the TCP/IP failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangeness on the part of the firewall. What wasn't working when i started the question now works. I tried executing the script referenced by the KB article without any change. Then re-defined a new rule that opened all ports, protocols, profiles, and programs - essentially duplicating the pre-existing rule. I found i had access. I disabled the new rule and still had access. [shrugging]

Answer (score 0):

This KB shows all the ports you need to allow in 2k8

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968872